# convert a Shell script to nodejs one

Tags: node.js, shell

I have written a shell script (`extract.sh`) that uses commands like `grep` , `sed`, `cut` over a log file `output.txt` to extract and append the content into some other "result" file. This "result" file is pushed to slack to display the content in required format.
Now for some reason I need to convert this shell script for NodeJS, I can see there are various NPM  modules (e.g easy-grep, tail etc. ) that seem to be doing similar work but I am still struggling to get the output the way I want.
Can you suggest what should be the NodeJS code for the below shell script?

Note: I don't wish to run the shell script via nodejs but want to have complete nodejs script.

```
=================================
output.txt  (log file)
=================================
Serverless: Compiling with Typescript...
Serverless: Using local tsconfig.json
Serverless: Typescript compiled.
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading artifacts...
Serverless: Uploading service abc-microservice.zip file to S3 (256.45 KB)...
Serverless: Validating template...
Serverless: Updating Stack...
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress...
abc-microservice.zip
.........................................
Serverless: Stack update finished...
Service Information
=================================
extract.sh    (my sample script)
=================================
if
        grep -i "failed" output.txt > /dev/null; [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
grep -i abc-microservice output.txt |tail -1|cut -d " " -f4 >> result.txt

else
        grep -i abc-microservice output.txt |grep -i stack| cut -d ":" -f2|tail -1 >> result.txt
=================================
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inbuilt package called child_process.
by using this you can run shell command from the nodejs application code.
example:

```
const spawn = require('child_process');
const vaultLogin = spawn.spawnSync('vault', ['login', '-method=github', '-path=github-platform', tokenArgs], { encoding : 'utf8' });
```